# Is it ok to use a 10 years old set of NiMH rechargeable AA batteries?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, nimh, battery-chemistry

I've just found my 10 year old pack of rechargeable NiMH AA and AAA batteries. The AAA ones are completely blown with a dark powder all over their positive terminals. The AA ones *look* fine when compared to the AAA ones.

[Photos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4puY.jpg)

**Set 1: Sony NH-AA HR15/51 1.2V typ.2700mAh**

There is slight rust in the positive terminal. No signs of swelling.

**Edit**: Open-circuit voltage measurements (no recharge!)

- `1.15V`; `1.17V`; `1.16V`; `1.16V`

**Set 2: Sony NH-AA HR15/51 1.2V typ.2500mAh**

Definitely looks swollen, but not as bad as swollen/blown motherboard Capacitors. It's hard to see the slight swelling in the pictures, but it's there.

Analyzing and confronting the two angles carefully (pay attention to the shadows of the plastic shell over the black surface), we can see the places where it is "fat". If I press those places with my finger nail, it rebounds like a foam (more like a "snap" or "buckle" than a foam resetting).

**Edit**: Open-circuit voltage measurements (no recharge!)

- `25mV`; `702mV`; `643mV`; `647mV`. Yes, there is a 25mV one!

### Question

1. Do you think there is a good chance that the batteries are as good as dead?
2. Do you think there is a good chance they will damage the device they're connected to? (the charger itself and a Xbox controller)
3. In the case they're probably dead, I think I will buy the [Panasonic Eneloop Pro](http://eneloop101.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/BK-3HCC.pdf) and charge them in my current charger which is this one (pictures and specs in the link above). Any problem with that or should I buy the Panasonic charger instead?

Comment: What's the open-circuit voltage on the AA cells?  If I had to guess, they're probably worthless at this point, but unlikely to damage a low-current device like a video game controller.  They wouldn't damage it electrically, the only plausible damage mechanism would be if they leak and corrode the contacts in the battery compartment.

Comment: @pericynthion Should I charge them first and then take the measurement?

Comment: @pericynthion Ok, here are the measurements without recharging (10 years idling!). Set 1 (rust 2700mAh): `1.15V`; `1.17V`; `1.16V`; `1.16V`. Set 2 (fat 2500mAh): `25mV`; `702mV`; `643mV`; `647mV`. Yes, there is a 25mV one, maybe that one is dead?

Comment: Definitely toss Set 2 - even the 600-700mV ones, especially since they're bulging.  Set 1 might be usable, they'll probably have degraded capacity.

Comment: @pericynthion Nice! I will try to use the Set 1. Thanks for the reminder of using my multimeter (without those reminders I'm dumb and don't use the tools that I have). So can we say that if an uncharged battery reads below ~`1V` it's pretty much dead? Thank you very much!

Comment: Close - the damage threshold for NiMH is somewhere around 0.8 to 0.9V.  Good luck. Hopefully the corrosion on the Set 1 cells is just deposits from the other decaying cells in the box with them.  I'd suggest looking at them every so often to make sure they aren't leaking into your controller.

Comment: @pericynthion Will do. And will do also buy those Eneloop from Panasonic and recharge them using the old charger (ok to do that, I'd assume?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60289/discussion-between-pericynthion-and-feelthhis).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Battery health and maintenance thereof is a complicated subject, and these rules are not necessarily always completely correct, but generally:

1. Any kind of swelling is a bad sign.  It means gas has been produced inside the cell, and it's not usually possible to put that gas back where it should be by electrochemical means.  It may also mean that the structural integrity of the cell has been compromised, so with further provocation it could leak or explode.  Any bulging cell should be safely disposed of; don't try to charge it.  If a cell is visibly leaking, the same applies - but in your case it's possible that the deposits of corroded material on your "Set 1" cells could have come from the other decomposing batteries in the storage container.
2. If the cell has been discharged below the "damage threshold" for that chemistry, particularly for an extended period of time, it's probably not going to be possible to revive it.  This discharging might have been from an external cause or it might have been the slow "self-discharge" that ~all batteries are subject to.  Charging might bring the voltage back up into the nominal range, but capacity will be vastly reduced.  Again, safe disposal is called for.  For NiMH this threshold is around 0.8 to 0.9V.
3. NiMH is relatively forgiving in terms of safety.  Probably the worst that will happen if you try to charge or use old or damaged cells is that they could leak, damaging the contacts on the equipment they're connected to.  Other chemistries such as lithium ion and NiCd are more of a safety hazard and can catch fire or explode if abused.
4. Usually you can use any NiMH charger with any NiMH cells.  Hopefully the charger is also still healthy after ten years... that's a long time for a consumer product.

Set 2 is definitely a lost cause.  Set 1 might be OK, though they're unlikely to have as much capacity as a fresh set.  You could do a capacity test to find out - charge them, then connect each to a separate 10 ohm resistor.  Note the voltage every 30 minutes until it reaches 1.0V.  If they really still have 2700 mAh capacity this should take around 20 hours - you can unplug it and stop counting while you sleep :)

It's a good idea to check the cells visually every so often while they're in use, to make sure they're not leaking into your X-box controller.